# SQL Table Valued Parameter - Default Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm passing a table valued parameter to a stored procedure to use in a where clause, but I want to check whether the parameter has been passed-in or not first. What is the best way to check a parameter of this type? For example, I want the select to be along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE
@TVP IS NULL OR RecordID IN (SELECT * FROM @TVP)
```

Comment: You should take a look at this article on the topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: The TVP is a table, not a variable. You can't say `WHERE dbo.tableName IS NULL` so try `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TVP)`. Also you should name the column instead of saying `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a parameter of a table valued type is not passed, it will just be an empty table.  So you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE not exists(select * from @TVP)
    or RecordID IN (SELECT * FROM @TVP)
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend bothering with a count, this requires a full scan which can be expensive if the TVP can be large.

Comment: Good point... I was just in the middle of editing my answer when your comment popped up.  :)